# the effect opacity in another position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little problem you have some pictures to capture it

http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_8768165captura-de-pantalla.png

That's an effect that makes CSS3 with JQuery that if I put the mouse over the image then place that has opacity would like to stay just above the orange box

**HTML**

```
<div class="mosaic-block bar">
  <a href="http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic" target="_blank" class="mosaic-overlay">
    <div class="details">
      <h4>Mosaic - Sliding Boxes and Captions jQuery Plugin</h4>
      <p>by Build Internet</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="img/blogprueba.jpg"/>
    <p id="entradabottom">La importancias de la seguridad en las empresas.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mosaic-block {
    width: 588px;
    height: 532px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px;

    z-index: 2;

    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#111 url(../img/progress.gif) no-repeat center center;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow-top:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow-left:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow-right:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.mosaic-backdrop {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:#111;
}

.mosaic-overlay {
    display:none;
    z-index:5;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#111;
}

.bar .mosaic-overlay {
    bottom:-100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.bar').mosaic({
        animation : 'slide'
    });
});
```

**attached file**

```
/*
    Mosaic - Sliding Boxes and Captions jQuery Plugin
    Version 1.0.1
    www.buildinternet.com/project/mosaic

    By Sam Dunn / One Mighty Roar (www.onemightyroar.com)
    Released under MIT License / GPL License
*/

(function($){

    if(!$.omr){
        $.omr = new Object();
    };

    $.omr.mosaic = function(el, options){

        var base = this;

        // Access to jQuery and DOM versions of element
        base.$el = $(el);
        base.el = el;

        // Add a reverse reference to the DOM object
        base.$el.data("omr.mosaic", base);

        base.init = function(){
            base.options = $.extend({},$.omr.mosaic.defaultOptions, options);

            base.load_box();
        };

        // Preload Images
        base.load_box = function(){
            // Hide until window loaded, then fade in
            if (base.options.preload){
                $(base.options.backdrop, base.el).hide();
                $(base.options.overlay, base.el).hide();

                $(window).load(function(){
                    // IE transparency fade fix
                    if(base.options.options.animation == 'fade' && $(base.options.overlay, base.el).css('opacity') == 0 ) $(base.options.overlay, base.el).css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=0)');

                    $(base.options.overlay, base.el).fadeIn(200, function(){
                        $(base.options.backdrop, base.el).fadeIn(200);
                    });

                    base.allow_hover();
                });
            }else{
                $(base.options.backdrop, base.el).show();
                $(base.options.overlay , base.el).show();
                base.allow_hover();
            }
        };

        // Initialize hover animations
        base.allow_hover = function(){
            // Select animation
            switch(base.options.animation){

                // Handle fade animations
                case 'fade':
                    $(base.el).hover(function () {
                        $(base.options.overlay, base.el).stop().fadeTo(base.options.speed, base.options.opacity);
                    },function () {
                        $(base.options.overlay, base.el).stop().fadeTo(base.options.speed, 0);
                    });

                    break;

                // Handle slide animations
                case 'slide':
                    // Grab default overlay x,y position
                    startX = $(base.options.overlay, base.el).css(base.options.anchor_x) != 'auto' ? $(base.options.overlay, base.el).css(base.options.anchor_x) : '0px';
                    startY = $(base.options.overlay, base.el).css(base.options.anchor_y) != 'auto' ? $(base.options.overlay, base.el).css(base.options.anchor_y) : '0px';;

                    var hoverState = {};
                    hoverState[base.options.anchor_x] = base.options.hover_x;
                    hoverState[base.options.anchor_y] = base.options.hover_y;

                    var endState = {};
                    endState[base.options.anchor_x] = startX;
                    endState[base.options.anchor_y] = startY;

                    $(base.el).hover(function () {
                        $(base.options.overlay, base.el).stop().animate(hoverState, base.options.speed);
                    },function () {
                        $(base.options.overlay, base.el).stop().animate(endState, base.options.speed);
                    });

                    break;
            };
        };

        // Make it go!
        base.init();
    };

    $.omr.mosaic.defaultOptions = {
        animation   : 'fade',
        speed       : 150,
        opacity     : 1,
        preload     : 0,
        anchor_x    : 'left',
        anchor_y    : 'bottom',
        hover_x     : '0px',
        hover_y     : '0px',
        overlay     : '.mosaic-overlay',    //Mosaic overlay
        backdrop    : '.mosaic-backdrop'    //Mosaic backdrop
    };

    $.fn.mosaic = function(options){
        return this.each(function(){
            (new $.omr.mosaic(this, options));
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Sorry, could you rephrase what is the issue here?

Comment: in the lower part of the image is an orange stripe on top and a slightly darker strip that you can see it is a bit higher, this is an effect that I get with JavaScript, and I intend that shadow begins just above the orange and not down the main strip box.